# Breaking up text document into sections with Python using Regex match on section titles

Tags: python, regex

The documents I have have sections that are nicely denoted by titles. I want to split the documents into sections using these titles. Example:

```
1.1 Lorem Ipsum

Blah blah blah
9 (page break, never will have a period in it though)
Bleh bleh bleh as referenced in Section 1.3 hey hey hey

1.2 Lorem Ipsumus

Blah blah blah
```

I would like a regex expression that can take the titles and the text until the next title appears. So the desired results for the example would be,

```
1.1 Lorem Ipsum Blah blah blah bleh bleh bleh as referenced in Section 1.3 hey hey hey
```

And

```
1.2 Lorem Ipsumus Blah blah blah
```

One thing I can always count on is that the section titles will be a new line that starts with some sort of number x.x followed by a few words and since that is pretty unique to the titles, that what I would like to search on.

Basically if I see anything that is a new line and of the form "Section 1.2 Definitions" I know that is a new section and would like to grab all the text from there until the next new line that starts with "Section 1.3 Examples" or perhaps "Section 2.1 Terms". Section titles always start a new line and are of the form "Section 1.3 Examples", "Article 1.3 Examples", or "1.3 Examples".

Sometimes there are references to titles in the middle of a line and these I would like to ignore. This can be seen in the example.

Does anyone know how to do this? Preferebly in python but the regex should be sufficient if not.

p.s. Keeping the page numbers or not is optional but the regex would ideally not create new sections based on the page numbers

---

EDIT: So far, here is the MWE I have running. Its not quite there.

```
import re
doc_splitter = re.compile(r"(?<=\n)(?P<secname>[\w]+ )(\d+\.\d+ .*?)(?<=\n)(?P<secname2>[\w]+ )(?=\d+\.\d+|\Z)", re.DOTALL)

text = """

Section 1.1 Lorem Ipsum

Blah blah blah
9
Bleh bleh bleh Section 1.1 hey hey hey

Section 1.2 Lorem Ipsumus 
ref Section 1.3

Blah blah blah

Section 1.3 hey hey

Section 1.4

"""


for match in doc_splitter.finditer(text):
    print([match.group()])
```

Ideally it would return:

```
['Section 1.1 Lorem Ipsum Blah blah blah 9 Bleh bleh bleh Section 1.1 hey hey hey']
['Section 1.2 Lorem Ipsumus ref Section 1.3 Blah blah blah']
['Section 1.3 hey hey']
['Section 1.4']
```

But instead it returns:

```
['Section 1.1 Lorem Ipsum\n\nBlah blah blah\n9\nBleh bleh bleh Section 1.1 hey hey hey\n\nSection ']
['Section 1.3 hey hey\n\nSection ']
```

Thanks for all the help everyone! If anyone has any thoughts on how to get this last problem fixed it would be very appreciated.

Comment: If I was just searching between 'Section' to 'Section' I think I could get it. This seems like much more than a simple regex expression though (I could be wrong) and if someone knows how to do it in a few minutes (like Arne below did) then it seems like a productive question to ask.

Comment: I also think it could be fairly relevant to others in a similar situation

Comment: Nit: If you give your sample in the form of a triple-string you offer your helpers unambiguous input =)

Comment: Got it. Will do that next time. :)

Comment: You could just split with this `(?m)(?!\A)(?=^\d+\.\d)` and you're done.

Comment: FWIW that gave me two blank strings when I put it into my MWE.

Comment: Please do not add the solution to your question. If you found a solution that worked best for you, then you can accept it below or answer your own question. This site encourages multiple solutions from other users, as the one that worked best for you may not work the best for someone else.

Comment: fyi, I added an alternative that works on your MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to put my two cents in - you could use

```
^
(?:Section\ )?\d+\.\d+
[\s\S]*?
(?=^(?:Section\ )?\d+\.\d+|\Z)
```

with the `verbose` and `multiline` modifier, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/qgYPxI/2).

---

In `Python`:

```
import re

data = """
1.1 Lorem Ipsum

Blah blah blah
9 (page break, never will have a period in it though)
Bleh bleh bleh as referenced in Section 1.3 hey hey hey

1.2 Lorem Ipsumus

Blah blah blah
"""

rx = re.compile(r'''
    ^
    (?:Section\ )?\d+\.\d+
    [\s\S]*?
    (?=^(?:Section\ )?\d+\.\d+|\Z)

    ''', re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)

parts = [match.group(0) for match in rx.finditer(data)]
print(parts)
```

Comment: Thanks Jan. I had figured out (via a different way) how to get the same result if the title only started with a number. But how would this change if '1.2' was occasionally 'Section 1.2' instead? Or could you make this work with the second example I give in the question?

Comment: @sfortney: Updated the answer and the demo.

Comment: Thats it! I tried that with my application (more than just the example above) and it worked too so I think it should be good. One final question, how would this change if the next clause could start with *either* 'Section 1.2' or 'Article 1.2'. Is there a way to make it so it doesn't matter if it is either one of those words (or none and just a number)? Would it just be as simple as replacing (?:Section\ ) with (?:[\w] )?

Comment: Either way I will accept your answer because it answered all my examples above. Thanks!

Comment: @sfortney: Just put it in the alternation (see https://regex101.com/r/qgYPxI/3). For the future, please put all your requirements in your question in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

The regex you are looking for might be similar to this:

```
doc_splitter = re.compile(r"(?<=\n)(\d+\.\d+ .*?)(?<=\n)(?=\d+\.\d+|$)", re.DOTALL)
```

, which, given python code, can be run on the whole document with `finditer`:

```
text = """
1.1 Lorem Ipsum

Blah blah blah
9 (page break, never will have a period in it though)
Bleh bleh bleh

1.2 Lorem Ipsumus

Blah blah blah"""
for match in doc_splitter.finditer(text):
    print([match.group()])  # print in list to suppress \n interpretation
```

Prints:

```
['1.1 Lorem Ipsum\n\nBlah blah blah\n9 (page break, never will have a period in it though)\nBleh bleh bleh\n\n']
['1.2 Lorem Ipsumus\n\nBlah blah blah\n']
```

which seems to be what you want.

If you iterate the data differently you might be able to get rid of the cumbersome lookaround assertions, which might not cleanly translate into other languages that demand constant length lookarounds. The core is given with `(\d+\.\d+ .*?)` and forcing a full match.

---

### Alternative

Jan's answer is good, but I also wanted to add a solution that solves the problem without lookahead conditions, since they look redundant:

```
import re
doc_splitter = re.compile(r"^(?:Section\ )?\d+\.\d+", re.MULTILINE)
text = """

Section 1.1 Lorem Ipsum

Blah blah blah
9
Bleh bleh bleh Section 1.1 hey hey hey

Section 1.2 Lorem Ipsumus 
ref Section 1.3

Blah blah blah

Section 1.3 hey hey

Section 1.4

"""
starts = [match.span()[0] for match in doc_splitter.finditer(text)] + [len(text)]
sections = [text[starts[idx]:starts[idx+1]] for idx in range(len(starts)-1)]
for section in sections:
    print([section])
```

Prints:

```
['Section 1.1 Lorem Ipsum\n\nBlah blah blah\n9\nBleh bleh bleh Section 1.1 hey hey hey\n\n']
['Section 1.2 Lorem Ipsumus \nref Section 1.3\n\nBlah blah blah\n\n']
['Section 1.3 hey hey\n\n']
['Section 1.4\n\n']
```

The regex only searches for the start of a new section, and should be easy enough to maintain and extend. We have to go through the additional step of splitting the `text` by hand from each new start, which serves as the ending for the former section.

While a regex is perfectly capable of handling this kind of matching in a single step, I personally prefer to keep them as short as possible. They are difficult enough to understand already.

Comment: Great thanks Arne! One more question to make it even cleaner. If I want to make this only apply when the line *starts* with "Section x.x', 'Article x.x' or 'x.x'. How would I do that? You don't have to reedit the whole answer with the python code btw.

Comment: By adding in a non-conditional of those strings at the beginning of the match, like so: `r"((Section )?(Article )?(\d+\.\d+ .*?))(?=\d+\.\d+|$)"`.

Comment: Also, once the regex gets more complicated, it might be a good idea to give the group that refers to the match you want to get a name: `r"(?P<my_name>(Section )?(Article )?(\d+\.\d+ .*?))(?=\d+\.\d+|$)"` and access it as `match.group('my_name')` instead. Helps with later readability a lot.

Comment: Cool thanks! I'll give that a try. Thanks for the help Arne!

Comment: Sorry one more question, above I wanted to make sure that the regex only caught the title if the line *started* with one of those three expressions (to avoid it tripping up on the sections being referenced in the middle of a line).  Is there a way to make it so that the regex only works if the expression is at the beginning of a line?

Comment: The non-conditional you mentioned catches things like 'Section 1.1' in the midde of a line and I only want to get titles which exclusively are at the start of lines. Sorry if my original question was confusing!

Comment: Yes, by including a lookahead that matches the start of the string or newlines. I included it in my answer, it should have been there from the beginning, you weren't ambiguous at all. Btw, I am on a mobile right now so I can't test changes any more. Sorry in advance for any mistakes

Comment: Thanks! No you have been very helpful :) One thing, when I run the MWE it gives: error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern .

Comment: If you are on mobile I can try to debug it myself no worries :)

Comment: Easy solution: remove the start of string condition from the lookahead `|^`, and prepend your text with a newline :p

Comment: I might just post an alternative later that isn't as convoluted, now that I understand the problem better.

Comment: Sounds good! Yeah I got the MWE to run but if there is a section title in the middle of the string it stops right at the mid-string section title. For example with: "Section 1.1 Blah blah blah refers to section 1.2 hey hey hey \n Section 1.2 bleh bleh bleh",   will only print,  "Section 1.1 Blah blah blah refers to section" for the first split and "Section 1.2 bleh bleh bleh" for the second split, missing the "hey hey hey"

Comment: Arne I am still working on this if you have any thoughts. I briefly thought I had it then I didn't.  What I am currently working with is this, doc_splitter = re.compile(r"(?<=\n)(?P<secname>[\w]+ )(\d+\.\d+ .*?)(?<=\n)(?P<secname2>[\w]+ )(?=\d+\.\d+|\Z)", re.DOTALL)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/), it will help you visualize your regex. Also, the [documentation for re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is very useful to learn (or remember) how the special characters work.

With your example I'd use this regex (with named groups):

```
(?P<section_number>\d\.\d) (?P<section_title>[\w ]+)\n\n\s*(?P<body>.+?)\s*(?=\d\.\d[\w ]+|$)
```

Breaking it down:

For the section number and title I used named groups `(?P<section_number>\d\.\d)` and `(?P<section_title>[\w ]+)` separated by a space.

The body `(?P<body>.+?)` is follwed by the positive lookahead `(?=\d\.\d[\w ]+|$)`. This means that it will stop capturing text when another section is about to begin or when the document ends. It needs to be nongreedy (`+?`) or you'll en up with just one section and the rest of the document as the body.

NOTE: you need to enable `re.DOTALL` when you compile or search for matches or the point will not match new line characters.

If you want the section title to match the beggining of a string you can also add a `^` to the lookahead but you need to enable `re.MULTILINE`. You'd also have to change the `$` at the end to `\Z` so it matches only the end of the document and not the end of every line.

```
(?P<section_number>\d\.\d) (?P<section_title>[\w ]+)\n\n\s*(?P<body>.+?)\s*(?=^\d\.\d[\w ]+|\Z)
```

Comment: Thank you izxle! This is awesome. Is there a way to make it so that this regex only catches text between titles at the *beginning* of a line? The titles always show up at the beginning of the line but sometimes there are references to the titles within the paragraphs which are not actually titles. I edited my question to make this more clear.   My convo with Arne also mentions this.

Comment: Yes, you can match a beginning of a line with the `^` but you neer to enable `re.MULTILINE` or it will only match the beginning of the document.

Comment: Thanks izxle! The problem with that is that if you run it on my MWE it ignores everything after Section 1.3

Comment: This one seems to do the trick. (?<=\n)(\d+\.\d+ .*?)(?<=\n)(?=\d+\.\d+|$)

Comment: @sfortney Did you try the one I suggested in my answer?

Comment: I did. Using (?P<section_number>\d\.\d) (?P<section_title>[\w ]+)\s+(?P<body>.+?)\s*(?=^\d\.\d[\w ]+|\Z) on my MWE returns three strings which is not the intended result. It looks like it is seeing the mid-phrase 'Section 1.3' in my MWE as a new section. I wanted it to ignore these 'red-herrings'. I also enabled re.MULTILINE.

Comment: That shouldn't happen because you have the `^\d\.\d` in the lookahead. So the body would include `blah Section 1.3 blah`. I do not know what a MWE is. The problem could be if `Section 1.3` is at the start of a line, to solve this you should add an explicit double linebreak after the section title. As so, `(?P<section_number>\d\.\d) (?P<section_title>[\w ]+)\n\n\s*(?P<body>.+?)\s*(?=^\d\.\d[\w ]+|\Z)`.

Comment: MWE is Minimal Working Example. Technically is is a piece of code that runs and does the basic job of what you want it to do. I was using the phrase kind of fast and loose here though to refer to my example I posted in the question which is bad form. Sorry. Let me try what you posted

Comment: Just tried running it and it only returns the second clause. The full python code is 

doc_splitter = re.compile(r"(?P<section_number>\d\.\d) (?P<section_title>[\w ]+)\n\n\s*(?P<body>.+?)\s*(?=^\d\.\d[\w ]+|\Z)", re.MULTILINE)

Comment: You are right izxle. It does get the next few phrases. The problem seems to be how the next instance of "Section" is included or not. It is kind of hard to explain in a comment but I will update my question to show what I am talking about.